# What is muleExtension APIkit in mule-project.xml?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm a Mule/Anypoint Studio beginner and have found the following line in my mule-project.xml file:

```
<muleExtension name="APIkit" qualifier="org.mule.tooling.apikit.3.7.0" />
```

Can anyone explain to me what effect this line has? Or point me in the direction of the documentation for mule-project.xml?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

mule-project.xml is only for use with Mule/Anypoint Studio, it's just the configuration file for your project setup including name, description, runtime and any additional modules you are using.

If you have dragged a component from the Mule palette, it will create a line in that file for the module if it's not a core component. So if you drag the APIKit component in it will add the module line to that file.

Comment: That makes sense. If I delete the line from the file, it doesn't seem to have any effect. Do you know at what point this line is actually used? Compile time? Run time?